# Searching home directory with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have this code that shows files that have been modified in the last 10 hours.

This works fine; however, I want it to do this only to the `home` directory. I tried putting `$HOME` as I had found with other examples of AWK taking from a specific directory; however, it didn't work. I realize this is not the best way to go about doing it, but it's an exercise for me, and `grep` is meant to be used; otherwise, I would definitely use `find`.

It's probably fairly simple, but I'm new to `bash` so it's pretty confusing to me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
echo "The files modified less than 10 hours ago are:"
ls -algG --time-style=+%s | grep ^[^d] | awk -vlimit=$(date +%s -d '10 hours ago') '$4 >   limit { print substr($0, index($0, $4) + length($4) + 1) }'
```

Comment: Did you try `ls -algG --time-style=+%s ${HOME} | grep ^[^d] | awk -vlimit=$(date +%s -d '10 hours ago') '$4 >   limit { print substr($0, index($0, $4) + length($4) + 1) }'`?

Comment: You never need grep with awk since awk can do RE comparions on it's own.

Answer (score 2):

I really would suggest to substitute your lengthy command with something simpler like

```
find ~ -not -type d -newermt '10 hours ago'
```

Check the documentation of `find(1)`.